# Introducir número en un array

Tags: java

Tengo un problema con el siguiente enunciado: Escribe un programa que sea capaz de insertar un dígito dentro de un número indicando la posición. El nuevo dígito se colocará en la posición indicada y el resto de dígitos se desplazará hacia la derecha.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Por favor, introduzca un número entero positivo:");
    String num = sc.next();
    String num1[] = num.split("");
    System.out.println("Introduce la posición donde quieres insertar");
    int pos = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Introduce el digito que quieres insertar");
    String dig = sc.next();
    for (int i = 0; i < num1.length; i++) {
        if (i == pos -1) {
            num1[pos-1] = dig;
        }
        System.out.print(num1[i]);
    }
```

Al ejecutarlo introduce el digito correctamente pero lo sustituye por el lugar donde he indicado, no lo desplaza hacia la derecha:

```
Por favor, introduzca un número entero positivo:12345

Introduce la posición donde quieres insertar 4
Introduce el digito que quieres insertar 9

12395
```

Answer (score 1):

Si te fijas, en tu código estás sustituyendo el valor de la posición del número original por el que metes en teclado y como ves por la salida, es lo que hace, no te desplaza los valores, para eso tienes que hacerlo así:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Por favor, introduzca un número entero positivo:");
String num = sc.next();
String num1[] = num.split("");
System.out.println("Introduce la posición donde quieres insertar");
int pos = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Introduce el digito que quieres insertar");
String dig = sc.next();
String aux="";

for(int i=0; i<num1.length; i++)
{
    if(i!=pos-1)
    {
        aux = aux + num1[i];  //Si no estamos en la posición a introducir, copiamos el número
    }else
    {
        aux = aux + dig + num1[i];  //Si estamos en la posición indicada, intercalamos el valor
    }
}
```

Comment: Funciona correctamente, pero no entiendo por qué hay que hacer eso en el else, es decir por qué se suma dig + num1

Comment: Si tomamos el caso de tu ejemplo, cuando es la posición 4, lo que hacemos es añadir el 9. Si no pones el + num1[i], no se añadiría el 4 que es el valor que hay en la posición original, prueba a quitarlo y verás que es esto lo que pasa

Answer (score 0):

También podrías hacer algo así:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Por favor, introduzca un número entero positivo:");
String num = sc.next();
System.out.println("Introduce la posición donde quieres insertar");
int pos = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Introduce el digito que quieres insertar");
String dig = sc.next();

//TODO comprobar que el indice se encuentre dentro de la longitud del numero    
//Obtenemos la parte izquierda del numero
String parte1 = num.substring(0, pos);
//Obtenemos la parte derecha del numero
String parte2 = num.substring(pos);
//Las juntamos
String result = parte1+dig+parte2;

return result;
```